# Enable push notifications via a UISwitch

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

I want to use a UISwitch to enable/disable push notifications. Like in Tweetbot.

Does anyone know how to trigger that?

Answer (score 1):

```
You can also do it in the following way.
create a IBOutlet for UISwitch  

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet *pushNotificationSwitch;

and in Action method, store the value in NSUserDefaults.


- (IBAction)pushNotificationSwitchChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSNumber *switch_value = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[self.pushNotificationSwitch isOn]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:switch_value forKey:RECIEVE_APNS];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

and check it in viewdidload.



- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

     NSNumber *sett = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:RECIEVE_APNS];
    if( [sett boolValue] )
    {

        [self.pushNotificationSwitch setOn:YES];

    }
    else{
        [self.pushNotificationSwitch setOn:NO];
    }

}

and In AppDelegate.m, add the following code

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo

{

    NSNumber *sett = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:RECIEVE_APNS];
    if( [sett boolValue] )
    {
        int currentBadgeCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"BadgeCount"];

        //Set the baadge count on the app icon in the home screen
        int badgeValue = [[[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"badge"] intValue];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeValue + currentBadgeCount;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:badgeValue + currentBadgeCount forKey:@"BadgeCount"];

        NSString *alertString = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];
        NSString *playSoundOnAlert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"sound"]];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],playSoundOnAlert]];
        NSError *error;

        if (alertString.length > 0)
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"App Name" message:alertString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
            audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 1;
            [audioPlayer play];
            [alert show];
        }

    }
}

    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that directly from the application. If you want to do this, you need to make the UISwitch send the information to your backend, store this information in your database and stop sending push notifications to this user.

Comment: No...that not what I meant. I want the switch to initialize the push notifications. I activate the switch and then I get the stock UIAlertView when an application is registering for push notifications

Answer (score 0):

An app registers for Push Notifications (APN) when it first launches. You cannot have it initialize APNs with a switch once it has already launched. You can however code your app that a switch can choose to do "something" with the user interface once a APN is received.

For example, you can have this code:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{
NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
NSString *alert = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];
// do what you need with the data...
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReceivedNotificationAlert" object:self];
}
```

You can use your UISwitch to either do something, or not, with the NSNotification "ReceivedNotificationAlert". For example:

```
if(switchAPNprocess.on){
// process APN
}
else {
// ignore APN
}
```